# How to get data or retrieve data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 through SOAPui

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, soapui, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I know it may be duplicate question, but in 2015 release I am facing some issue while getting data.

I have read all blogs related to this subject, but could not make it.

I have followed below steps to get data.

1. Loaded project in SOAPui from http://{server}/{OrgName}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
2. Edited endpoint, Added /web after Organisation.svc
3. Added Authentication. (username,password,domain)
4. Added content-type, SOAPAction, Accept

Still I am getting Bad-Request error.

please help. If possible please give some Request sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you validated the request in the soapui request editor? Also see the raw request to find all the details are sent. And go to the preferences to include the security details for outgoing requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to setup requests, make sure you're setup correctly:

1. Create a SOAP project pointing to `http://<organization url>/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl` (you'll have to authenticate)
2. Create a new request for w/e you need to do
3. In the request, set `Authentication` to `NTLM` (provide credentials)
4. In the request, you'll need three `Headers` like this (double-check them if you already have them there):

   4.1. `SOAPAction` - copy/paste it from the request interface properties

   4.2 `Accept` - `application/xml, text/xml, */*`

   4.3 `Content-Type` - `text/xml; charset=utf-8`
5. Provide a well-formed request and go

For example, this is what a `RetrieveEntityRequest` looks like (this in particular will return the metadata of the `account` entity):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header><a:SdkClientVersion xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">6.0</a:SdkClientVersion></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
 <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request i:type="a:RetrieveEntityRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
   <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>EntityFilters</b:key>
     <b:value i:type="c:EntityFilters" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata">Attributes</b:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>MetadataId</b:key>
     <b:value i:type="ser:guid"  xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>RetrieveAsIfPublished</b:key>
     <b:value i:type="c:boolean" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</b:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>LogicalName</b:key>
       <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">account</b:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
   </a:Parameters>
   <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
   <a:RequestName>RetrieveEntity</a:RequestName>
  </request>
 </Execute>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you help me to find out other requests ?

Comment: this is a quite comprehensive list http://mileyja.blogspot.it/p/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-sdk-example.html